# Newton's iteration for root finding

Tags: matlab

I am writing a function which implements Newton's iteration for root-finding on a scalar function, i.e., find x such that f(x)=0, and x_(n+1) = x_n - [f(x_n)/f'(x_n)].

f1 and f1prime are the handles to compute f and f', and x0 is an initial root estimate, and 'tol' is the toleratnce. I have to continue the iteration until either |f(x_n+1)| is less than tol or I have exceeded 10^5 iterations. And, the output of the function is x_n+1.
Also... f(x)=3x^4-5x^3-12x^2 where f'(x)=12x^3-15x^2-24x.

My current code is...

```
f1=@(x) 3*x^4 -5*x^3 - 12*x^2;
f1prime=@(x) 12*x^3-15*x^2-24*x;
n=0;
root=x0;
    while abs(f1(x(n+1))<tol ||n>10^5
    x(n+1)=x(n)-f1(x(n))/fprime(x(n));
    n=n+1;
end
```

My code should pass this test suite, but it did not. What is the problem of the above code?

```
tol=1e-6;
f1=@(x) 3*x^4 -5*x^3 - 12*x^2;
f1prime=@(x) 12*x^3-15*x^2-24*x;
x0=-1;
root_correct = [-1.333333];
[root]=newtonRoot(f1,f1prime,x0,tol);
tol1=1e-4;
assert( abs(root-root_correct) < tol1 , ...
 [ '\nYour output \n root = [' sprintf(' %d ',root) ']\n'   ...
   'Expected output \n root = [' sprintf(' %d ',root_correct) ']\n'   ], ...
   root,root_correct);
```

Comment: 10^5 as an iteration limit is absurd. The Newton method is well known for its quadratic convergence. Assuming the initial value has 1 correct bit, the next iterates will have 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64... correct bits. So the number of iterations better be close to 10 than 100000. (Allow some margin anyway as the initial value can have "less" than 1 exact bit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping condition is not correct:

```
while abs(f1(x(n+1)) < tol || n>10^5
```

continues as long as the absolute value of `f1` is less than `tol` and `n` is greater than `10^5`. Both conditions are not valid in the first iteration, thus you do not even iterate Newtons method once.

Try:

```
while abs(f1(x(n+1)) > tol && n < 10^5
```